# Change color for certain words in a sentence

Tags: python, string

I have a string in Python.

```
string ="Marry had. A little lamb"
```

and a string that contains some words from the first string

```
part="had. lamb"
```

I need to print the first string and change color for the words from the second string.

Where I am now.

```
class c:
    blue = '\033[94m'
    red =  '\033[93m'

string ="Marry had. A little lamb"
part =" had. lamb"

pos= [string.split().index(t) for t in part.split()]
print(pos) # prints [1, 4]
print c.blue+(string) #prints string in blue needs to print 1 and 4 from pos in red
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you are overcomplicating things. A `split` to change `parts` into a list, followed by iterating over the individual words in `string` and testing if they appear in `parts`, seems all that's necessary:

```
>>> partwords = part.split()
>>> for w in string.split():
...   if w in partwords:
...     print c.red+w,
...   else:
...     print c.blue+w,
```

Result (and yes, your escape code is for yellow, not for red):

[image: Marry in colour]